# for loop causing infinite loading wait

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml, infinite-loop

I'm writing a PHP script which contains the following `for` loop:

```
for($x=count($content->data->parameters[0]->weather->children());$content->data->weather->{"weather-conditions"}[$x]['weather-type']==NULL;--$x){
    echo $x."\n";
}
```

Where $content is an instance of SimpleXMLElement, which has parsed XML like the following:

```
<dwml xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd">
<data>
<parameters applicable-location="point1">
<location>
<weather time-layout="k-p3h-n41-3">
<name>Weather Type, Coverage, and Intensity</name>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="likely" intensity="light" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="definitely" intensity="light" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="definitely" intensity="light" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="definitely" intensity="moderate" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
<value coverage="areas" intensity="none" additive="and" weather-type="blowing snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="definitely" intensity="moderate" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
<value coverage="areas" intensity="none" additive="and" weather-type="blowing snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="definitely" intensity="moderate" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
<value coverage="areas" intensity="none" additive="and" weather-type="blowing snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="definitely" intensity="moderate" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
<value coverage="areas" intensity="none" additive="and" weather-type="blowing snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
<value coverage="areas" intensity="none" additive="and" weather-type="blowing snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
<value coverage="areas" intensity="none" additive="and" weather-type="blowing snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="snow showers" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="snow showers" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="snow showers" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="snow showers" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions/>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" additive="and" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" additive="and" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
<value coverage="chance" intensity="light" additive="and" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
<value coverage="chance" intensity="light" additive="and" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
<weather-conditions>
<value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
<value coverage="chance" intensity="light" additive="and" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
<visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
</value>
</weather-conditions>
</weather>
</parameters>
</data>
</dwml>
```

EDIT: After parsing this file, this is what `var_dump($content->data->parameters[0]->weather);` yields:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (3) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["time-layout"]=>
    string(11) "k-p3h-n41-3"
  }
  ["name"]=>
  string(37) "Weather Type, Coverage, and Intensity"
  ["weather-conditions"]=>
  array(41) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["coverage"]=>
          string(13) "slight chance"
          ["intensity"]=>
          string(5) "light"
          ["weather-type"]=>
          string(4) "snow"
          ["qualifier"]=>
          string(4) "none"
        }
        ["visibility"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (0) {
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["coverage"]=>
          string(13) "slight chance"
          ["intensity"]=>
          string(5) "light"
          ["weather-type"]=>
          string(4) "snow"
          ["qualifier"]=>
          string(4) "none"
        }
        ["visibility"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (0) {
        }
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["coverage"]=>
          string(6) "chance"
          ["intensity"]=>
          string(5) "light"
          ["weather-type"]=>
          string(4) "snow"
          ["qualifier"]=>
          string(4) "none"
        }
        ["visibility"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (0) {
        }
      }
    }
    [3]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["coverage"]=>
          string(6) "likely"
          ["intensity"]=>
          string(5) "light"
          ["weather-type"]=>
          string(4) "snow"
          ["qualifier"]=>
          string(4) "none"
        }
        ["visibility"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (0) {
        }
      }
    }
    [4]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["coverage"]=>
          string(10) "definitely"
          ["intensity"]=>
          string(5) "light"
          ["weather-type"]=>
          string(4) "snow"
          ["qualifier"]=>
          string(4) "none"
        }
        ["visibility"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (0) {
        }
      }
    }
    [5]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["coverage"]=>
          string(10) "definitely"
          ["intensity"]=>
          string(5) "light"
          ["weather-type"]=>
          string(4) "snow"
          ["qualifier"]=>
          string(4) "none"
        }
        ["visibility"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (0) {
        }
      }
    }
    [6]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["coverage"]=>
            string(10) "definitely"
            ["intensity"]=>
            string(8) "moderate"
            ["weather-type"]=>
            string(4) "snow"
            ["qualifier"]=>
            string(4) "none"
          }
          ["visibility"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (0) {
          }
        }
        [1]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(5) {
            ["coverage"]=>
            string(5) "areas"
            ["intensity"]=>
            string(4) "none"
            ["additive"]=>
            string(3) "and"
            ["weather-type"]=>
            string(12) "blowing snow"
            ["qualifier"]=>
            string(4) "none"
          }
          ["visibility"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [7]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["coverage"]=>
            string(10) "definitely"
            ["intensity"]=>
            string(8) "moderate"
            ["weather-type"]=>
            string(4) "snow"
            ["qualifier"]=>
            string(4) "none"
          }
          ["visibility"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (0) {
          }
        }
        [1]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(5) {
            ["coverage"]=>
            string(5) "areas"
            ["intensity"]=>
            string(4) "none"
            ["additive"]=>
            string(3) "and"
            ["weather-type"]=>
            string(12) "blowing snow"
            ["qualifier"]=>
            string(4) "none"
          }
          ["visibility"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [8]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["coverage"]=>
            string(10) "definitely"
            ["intensity"]=>
            string(8) "moderate"
            ["weather-type"]=>
            string(4) "snow"
            ["qualifier"]=>
            string(4) "none"
          }
          ["visibility"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (0) {
          }
        }
        [1]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(5) {
            ["coverage"]=>
            string(5) "areas"
            ["intensity"]=>
            string(4) "none"
            ["additive"]=>
            string(3) "and"
            ["weather-type"]=>
            string(12) "blowing snow"
            ["qualifier"]=>
            string(4) "none"
          }
          ["visibility"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [9]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["coverage"]=>
            string(10) "definitely"
            ["intensity"]=>
            string(8) "moderate"
            ["weather-type"]=>
            string(4) "snow"
            ["qualifier"]=>
            string(4) "none"
          }
          ["visibility"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (0) {
          }
        }
        [1]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(5) {
            ["coverage"]=>
            string(5) "areas"
            ["intensity"]=>
            string(4) "none"
            ["additive"]=>
            string(3) "and"
            ["weather-type"]=>
            string(12) "blowing snow"
            ["qualifier"]=>
            string(4) "none"
          }
          ["visibility"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [10]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["coverage"]=>
            string(6) "chance"
            ["intensity"]=>
            string(5) "light"
            ["weather-type"]=>
            string(4) "snow"
            ["qualifier"]=>
            string(4) "none"
          }
          ["visibility"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (0) {
          }
        }
        [1]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(5) {
            ["coverage"]=>
            string(5) "areas"
            ["intensity"]=>
            string(4) "none"
            ["additive"]=>
            string(3) "and"
            ["weather-type"]=>
            string(12) "blowing snow"
            ["qualifier"]=>
            string(4) "none"
          }
          ["visibility"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
...//More in here, trivial.
    [40]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#44 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["coverage"]=>
            string(6) "chance"
            ["intensity"]=>
            string(5) "light"
            ["weather-type"]=>
            string(4) "rain"
            ["qualifier"]=>
            string(4) "none"
          }
          ["visibility"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (0) {
          }
        }
        [1]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(5) {
            ["coverage"]=>
            string(6) "chance"
            ["intensity"]=>
            string(5) "light"
            ["additive"]=>
            string(3) "and"
            ["weather-type"]=>
            string(4) "snow"
            ["qualifier"]=>
            string(4) "none"
          }
          ["visibility"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since the elements at the end will sometimes be empty, and I want the latest non-empty weather item, I set x to the index of the last item in the weather array, and tried to work backwards, but the page just doesn't load, and there's nothing in the error log.
EDIT: I've changed the method to this in an attempt to make it easier to understand:

```
for($x=0; $content->data->parameters[0]->weather->{"weather-conditions"}[count($content->data->parameters[0]->weather->children())-$x]['weather-type']==NULL; $x++){
    echo $x."\n";
}
```

**EDIT**: In case it wasn't clear, I need to recurse backwards through the array of children, not forwards.

Comment: May i ask why you not just use a foreach for this?

Comment: Because it seemed easier to use this method to recurse backwards through the child nodes.

Comment: If you need to go through an array backwards, why not use `array_reverse` to reverse the array, and loop through it like normal?

Comment: @Axel `$weather_children=array_reverse($content->data->parameters[0]->weather->children()); var_dump($weather_children);` yields NULL.

Comment: But `var_dump($content->data->parameters[0]->weather->children());` yields actual content.

Comment: That's because `$content->data->parameters[0]->weather->children()` is an object, not an array.  What is your primary objective?  What are you trying to achieve with the XML data you're parsing through?

Comment: I was trying to parse down to the weather conditions and pull out the last non-null object of that array. I fixed my problem - turned out I was skipping a couple of levels in the hierarchy. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @AehmloLxaitn: You should use xpath if you traverse more deep. It will allow you to select/query the element(s) you need/want specifically, I added an answer discussing that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15219882/367456 - please see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some various issues I could find in your question:

**The XML is invalid.** Please provide working data when asking a question, here the `<location>` element got opened and never closed. The rest of my answer has the pre-condition that this start-tag has been *removed*.

**The endless loop is not prevented.** It makes no sense that `$x` goes below 0 but you don't check for that. You *should* add such a check so that you don't create an endless loop just because you made some error with another part of the break decision logic:

```
for (
    $x = count($content->data->parameters[0]->weather->children());
    $x >= 0 && $content->data->weather->{"weather-conditions"}[$x]['weather-type'] == NULL;
    --$x
) {
    echo $x . "\n";
}
```

With the (fixed) example data this will now count from 42 down to 0 but not below 0. At least the infinite loop has been removed. After clearing out these technical issues you could then focus on the problem domain:

> Since the elements at the end will sometimes be empty, and I want the latest non-empty weather item

Well, your actual sample XML does not contain *any* empty `<weather>` elements (that are `<weather>` elements not having any children. So it's not clear what you're asking about.

However it contains empty  `<weather-conditions/>` elements so as a precondition for the rest of the answer I take that instead.

XML has no specific order - at least not by design - and as your example XML shows, the empty `<weather-conditions/>` elements are more in the middle of the document and not at the end. What you actually want are all  `<weather-conditions>` elements that contain child elements (here `<value>`). You do this best with an xpath query.

So you first query all the elements that *have* `<value>` children and then you take the last element (in document order). So here we go:

```
list($lastCondition) = $content->xpath('
    (
        /*/data/parameters/weather/weather-conditions[value]
    )[position() = last()]
');
```

The variable `$lastCondition` then contains that last non-empty element, here as XML output based on your example XML:

```
<weather-conditions>
                    <value coverage="chance" intensity="light" weather-type="rain" qualifier="none">
                        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
                    </value>
                    <value coverage="chance" intensity="light" additive="and" weather-type="snow" qualifier="none">
                        <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
                    </value>
                </weather-conditions>
```

As you can see there are a lot of thing not clear with your question which made it harder to answer. In the end I hope this is still helpful.

The method used is [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.xpath), Xpath 1.0 (used by that method) is specified on the W3C site [XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), Stackoverflow itself contains a lot of examples, so it's always a good bet to search here first.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was skipping a couple of levels in the heirarchy, which was why the condition checking if the strings were NULL was always returning TRUE (hence the infinite loop). Final code:

```
for($x=count($content->data->parameters[0]->weather->children()); $x>0; $x--){
    if($content->data->parameters[0]->weather->{"weather-conditions"}[$x]!=NULL){
        return $content->data->parameters[0]->weather->{"weather-conditions"}[$x][0]->value['weather-type'];
    }
}
```